# How to compile Ruby Extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rakefile

I have a simple extension in ext/Q/flagvalue.c

My ext/Q/extconfig.rb looks like this:

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('Q/flagvalue')
```

The task in Rakefile is set-up just so:

```
Rake::ExtensionTask.new("Q") do |extension|
  extension.lib_dir = 'lib/Q'
end
```

when I `rake build`, i get the following output:

```
mkdir -p tmp/x86_64-linux/Q/1.9.3
cd tmp/x86_64-linux/Q/1.9.3
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby -I. ../../../../ext/Q/extconf.rb
creating Makefile
cd -
cd tmp/x86_64-linux/Q/1.9.3
make
compiling ../../../../ext/Q/flagvalue.c
linking shared-object Q/flagvalue.so
cd -
install -c tmp/x86_64-linux/Q/1.9.3/Q.so lib/Q/Q.so
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - tmp/x86_64-linux/Q/1.9.3/Q.so
```

So it seems like the compiler compiles and links **flagvalue.so** and the installer tries to install non-existent **Q.so**… where does this error come from and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some digging (and some vague guessing :-Δ) I found the solution:

I just got some code for my gemspec (from [Writehack.com](http://writehack.com/2011/1/30/Packaging%20a%20Ruby%20C%20Extension%20as%20a%20Gem)), that was so:

```
s.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
```

the problem with this method is that you'd have to have the just-to compile-binaries already in your repository. the correct way was to get the *.c-files from ext-directory and rename them to *.so like this:

```
s.executables   = s.files.grep(%r{^ext/.*c$}).map{ |f| File.basename(f, '.c') + '.so'}
s.bindir        = 'bin'
```

and also adding a bindir to `Rakefile`'s ExtensionTask and make it get its files from spec:

```
spec = Gem::Specification.load('Q.gemspec')
spec.executables.each do |f|
  Rake::ExtensionTask.new('Q', spec) do |ext|
    ext.name    = f.gsub(/\.so$/,'')
    ext.tmp_dir = 'tmp'
    ext.lib_dir = 'bin'
  end
end
```

:-Δ

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `Rakefile`:

```
Rake::ExtensionTask.new 'flagvalue' do |extension|
  extension.ext_dir = 'ext/Q'
  extension.lib_dir = 'lib/Q'
end
```

This does entail some duplication, as the Rake tasks doesn’t know what you specify as your target in `extconf` (i.e. it doesn’t know about the `Q` directory), so you have to specify again. This also means there won’t be a `Q` directory in the structure the the task creates under the `tmp` dir in your project, but that’s probably not a problem.